Freeform / ClickDimension integration - Hidden field data too long
I'm trying to integrate a form with ClickDimension using the POST Forwarding option.
From Postman, I am able to submit form data to ClickDimension without any problem. ClickDimension requires hidden fields with keys in order to submit.
One of these fields (cd_postsettings) has a value of over 18,000 characters. Craft/Freeform doesn't let that amount of data through, and the user receives an error message.
When I reduce the number of characters in the hidden field, it goes through, but ClickDimension obviously doesn't accept the submission because it doesn't recognize the associated form.
I can't act on the hidden field value from CD. I've disabled the option in Freeform to store submission values.
What option do I have ?
